# Mailbox Simulator for the Amazon Simple Email Service

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

As mentioned in AWS [Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mailbox-simulator-for-the-amazon-simple-email-service/),

> Today we are introducing the Amazon SES Mailbox Simulator to allow you to test your application without affecting your sending quota or the bounce and complaint metrics that drive it. **You can now send test emails to specific email addresses hosted by the mailbox simulator. Each address has a specific, defined response**. You can send email to these new addresses even if you are still running in the Amazon SES sandbox.

I am using PHPMailer for for testing mailbox simulator code below

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$emp_email="bounce@simulator.amazonses.com";
$emp_name="testbounce";
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Disable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'sesusername';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password =  'sespassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to 

    $mail->From = 'testmail@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = "testname";
    $mail->addAddress($emp_email,$emp_name);

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I am getting error as

> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: testname , testmail@example.com SMTP code: 554

As I know for sending email using SES we need verified **From** mail id in general way.

So how to configure simulator to test new email id.

Answer (score 1):

All addresses that you send from must be verified. You can do this via the console or via API. [See the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html). You can also [verify an entire domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domain-procedure.html).

Comment: thanks for your time but I want to know how to verify the bulk email address before sending. It affect the reputation statistic(bounces etc) if they are incorrect. Does AWS provides services  to verify the bulk email ids

Comment: AWS does not provide email verification. Try Kickbox.com